# Update/Reload/refresh Fragment from MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem with my fragments. I've only three fragments, and in the right side I have a fragment with a historical listView, and I want to update when I take a picture. But this fragment only update when I move to left side. But I want to update when I'm in the middle too, or for example when I end up to take a picture.

I can't call onCreateView(...) obviously. What's the easiest solution if I want to call from MainAcitivty to FragmentAdapter?
(FragmentAdapter; where is my onCreateView with inflater.inflate(R....)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your fragment to update the listview and make it static or create a static instance of your fragment and call the method in your activity when your app comes back from the camera inside your onactivityresult call.

EDIT:

you could just set up a static method in your fragment and call it anywhere like this.

in your fragment and in this sample lets say its called MyFragment:

```
public static void doSomething(Intent data){

          //do something with data from camera

  }
```

then in your activity's onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{

         MyFragment.doSomething(data);

 }
```

Comment: Fair enough, but I want to callOncreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) and I can't call it because I don't have inflater and container.

Comment: And I need them. (view, inflater, container)

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.historic, container, false);

Comment: If your fragment is or has been instantiated correctly then the onCreateView call will have already been called and all the layout and its views should be inflated. Unless your destroying the fragment when the camera opens you should be able to call the fragment method in the activities return. I know because I do this a lot when using the camera :)